# I have one issue on ListView

Tags: android

I want to implement refine on my app where the item will come from server but in the below Custom_List class code only one item is coming and another item is shown as null.[This is screenshot of items.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pim8H.png)
On this item I am retrieving id,age,height,communities,caste,occupation,education,income,location,pics.

```
public class RefineCustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
private NetworkImageView imageView;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private final String[] ids;
private String[] ages;
private String[] heights;
public String[] communities;
public String[] castes;
public String[] educations;
public String[] occupations;
public String[] incomes;
public String[] pics;
public String[] locations;
public String[] shortlist;
public String[] expressinterest;
private Activity context;

public RefineCustomList(Activity context, String[] ids, String[] ages, String[] heights, String[] communities, String[] castes,
                        String[] educations, String[] occupations, String[]incomes, String[]pics, String[] locations,
                        String[] shortlist, String[] expressinterest) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view_layout,ids);
    this.ids = ids;
    this.ages = ages;
    this.heights = heights;
    this.communities = communities;
    this.castes = castes;
    this.educations = educations;
    this.occupations = occupations;
    this.incomes = incomes;
    this.pics = pics;
    this.locations = locations;
    this.context = context;
    this.shortlist = shortlist;
    this.expressinterest = expressinterest;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refine_custom_list, null, true);

    String url1 = "https://www.maangal.com/thumb/thumb_";
    String url =url1+pics[position];

    imageView = (NetworkImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.offer_image);
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getContext()).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get(url, ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,R.drawable.image,android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));
    imageView.setImageUrl(url,imageLoader);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);

    textViewId.setText(ids[position]);
    textViewName.setText( ages[position]+" years"+" , "+heights[position]+" cm"+", "+communities[position]+" : "+castes[position]+" , "+educations[position]+" , "+occupations[position]+" , "+incomes[position]+", "+locations[position]);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), BlankActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ids[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i.putExtra("id", ids[position]);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button btnSort =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnshort);
    btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Shortlisted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Button btnChat =(Button) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.btnchat);
    btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Chatting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    Button declineButton = (Button)listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.declineButton);
    declineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Decline",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return listViewItem;
}

}
```

This is the parsing code

```
 public class RefineActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SessionManager session;
String email;

public String JSON_URL;
private ListView listView;
Button rfb;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.refine_activity);
    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(this);
    // get user data from session
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    email = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMAIL);
    Log.e("email==========>", email);
    //JSON_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/xp/ei_sent_pending.php?matri_id="+email;

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    rfb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refineBtn);
    rfb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            RefineFragment ls_fragment = new RefineFragment();
            ls_fragment.show(fragmentManager, "simple fragment");
        }
    });
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String response = getIntent().getExtras().getString("res");
    Log.e("responde rfi", response);
    showJSON(response);
}

protected void showJSON(String json) {
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    RefineCustomList cl = new RefineCustomList(this, ParseJSON.ids, ParseJSON.ages, ParseJSON.heights, ParseJSON.communities, ParseJSON.castes, ParseJSON.educations, ParseJSON.occupations, ParseJSON.incomes, ParseJSON.pics, ParseJSON.locations, ParseJSON.shortlist, ParseJSON.expressinterest);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
  }
}
```

This is the Log where the item data is showing

```
      responde rfi: {"result":[{"id":"Mgl11638","age":"21","height":"160","caste":"Brahmin","community":"Kumaoni","education":"MA","occupation":"Not Working","income":"Will tell later","pic":"Mgl11638.jpg","location":"Almora"},{"id":"Mgl16111","age":"22","height":"160","caste":"Brahmin","community":"Kumaoni","education":"B.Sc","occupation":"Student","income":"Will tell later","pic":"","location":"Almora"},{"id":"Mgl11658","age":"22","height":"154","caste":"Brahmin","community":"Kumaoni","education":"Undergraduate","occupation":"Student","income":"Will tell later","pic":"","location":"Lucknow"},{"id":"Mgl11621","age":"21","height":"134","caste":"Brahmin","community":"Kumaoni","education":"MA","occupation":"Not Working","income":"No income","pic":"","location":"Bareilly"}]}
```

Comment: It looks like other array items are empty. Show your code where you are parsing data.

Comment: Most probably error in setting your adapter. However, one suggestion, instead of using so many arrays simply create a POJO class and pass List of object into your adapter.

Comment: ListView, what is that ? Consider using recycler view, please.

Comment: @hcknl, It is compulsory to use the recycler view. I think this is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use too much of Arrays inside an adapter? Just follow these steps.

1. Put all your strings inside an Object as single fields.
2. Pass that object as a parameter into your adapter from your Activity.
3. Fetch the details from that object in your adapter.

Then the adapter will automatically fetch you multiple data and populate into the list view. And my kind advice is to extend the class as ***BaseAdapter*** instead of ***ArrayAdapter***

This is your object. I created it exclusively for you. Create a new java class(not an activity, just a `.java` file) and put this code inside.

```
public class DetailsObject implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String id;
private String age;
private String height;
public String community;
public String caste;
public String education;
public String occupation;
public String income;
public byte[] pic;
public String location;
public String shortlist;
public String expressinterest;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public String getCommunity() {
    return community;
}

public void setCommunity(String community) {
    this.community = community;
}

public String getCaste() {
    return caste;
}

public void setCaste(String caste) {
    this.caste = caste;
}

public String getEducation() {
    return education;
}

public void setEducation(String education) {
    this.education = education;
}

public String getOccupation() {
    return occupation;
}

public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
    this.occupation = occupation;
}

public String getIncome() {
    return income;
}

public void setIncome(String income) {
    this.income = income;
}

public byte[] getPic() {
    return pic;
}

public void setPic(byte[] pic) {
    this.pic = pic;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getShortlist() {
    return shortlist;
}

public void setShortlist(String shortlist) {
    this.shortlist = shortlist;
}

public String getExpressinterest() {
    return expressinterest;
}

public void setExpressinterest(String expressinterest) {
    this.expressinterest = expressinterest;
}
}
```

In your adapter class change `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` to `extends BaseAdapter`, change all the `String[]` to `String` and in the constructor, juzt pass `(Context context, DetailsObject detailObject)` as parameter. And in your activity call the adapter like below:

```
RefineCustomList refineCustomList;
refineCustomList = new RefineCustomList(MainActivity.this,detailObject);
yourListView.setAdapter(refineCustomList);
```

Thats it..

Comment: Can you send me a link where we can read and implement that type of code. I am new on android.

Comment: You just need to create POJO classes and then GSON will help you to parse Json Data. [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) or [here](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Comment: I have created this code same as you said now what should I do.

Comment: In your adapter class change `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` to extends BaseAdapter `

Comment: Now I am implementing your code but tell me what is the problem on my code because all the item is coming on response but not come in listview

Comment: There is an error on activity class where I used below line at detailObject                                                
    refineCustomList = new RefineCustomList(MainActivity.this,detailObject);

Comment: could u post the `LogCat`?

Comment: I think you might not have declared the `detailObject`. You should populate the data from your `url` into `detailObject`, i.e., from your webservice.

Comment: I have also implemented same code for shortlist the item and that code is running successfully.